# DOM not passing attribute as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an anchor element: `<a href="#ItemPage" class="ItemLink" rel="modal:open" id="' . $row['number']. '">` This opens a modal I found [here](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal#installation). My problem is the `id=""` isn't passing into my jQuery's `ItemNumber` variable as expected:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ItemLink').on('click', function() {
    var ItemNumber = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'Item.php?number=' + ItemNumber,
      data: {
        ItemNumber: ItemNumber
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#StoneDetails').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Modal -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!--id will have placeholder for testing-->
  <a href="#ItemPage" class="ItemLink" rel="modal:open" id="999">
dynamic info</a>

  <!-- Modal for product page -->
  <div id="ItemPage" class="modal">
    <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="CloseModal">
      <span class="mdi mdi-close mdi-36px"></span>
      <!-- Ignore this; it's for a font I found online -->
    </a>
    <div id="StoneDetails"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

If I change `var ItemNumber =` to `$('.ItemLink').attr('id');` I get the attribute of just the first element. I have a page of a bunch of dynamic links where I want the modal to open with the Item.php and the data for the clicked link dynamically by getting the `id=""` attribute. What am I doing wrong in my function?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204758/discussion-on-question-by-ariel-zabihi-dom-not-passing-attribute-as-expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ItemLink').on('click', function() {
    var ItemNumber = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(ItemNumber);

    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'Item.php?number=' + ItemNumber,
      data: {
        ItemNumber: ItemNumber
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#StoneDetails').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Modal -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <!--id will have placeholder for testing-->
  <a href="#ItemPage" class="ItemLink" rel="modal:open" data-id="999">
dynamic info</a>

<a href="#ItemPage" class="ItemLink" rel="modal:open" data-id="911">
dynamic info 2</a>

<a href="#ItemPage" class="ItemLink" rel="modal:open" data-id="922">
dynamic info 3</a>

  <!-- Modal for product page -->
  <div id="ItemPage" class="modal">
    <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="CloseModal">
      <span class="mdi mdi-close mdi-36px"></span>
      <!-- Ignore this; it's for a font I found online -->
    </a>
    <div id="StoneDetails"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

EDIT:

Your Item.js should be as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.ItemLink', function(){
    var ItemNumber = $(this).attr('id');
      alert(ItemNumber);

      $.ajax({

          url: 'Item.php?number=' + ItemNumber, 
          method: 'POST',
          data: {ItemNumber: ItemNumber},  
          success:

              function(data) {

                  $('#StoneDetails').html(data);

              }

      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Adding an alert function and changing `id` to `data-id` on the anchor and on the variable that gets the attribute for for the anchor still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works in the snippet but not my actual code. I can't figure out why.

Comment: There isn't any output, but I know I linked the .js file correctly as when I view source and click the file it directs correctly

Comment: You didn't get alert anymore? Please edit and post your new code so I can help.

Comment: That's the thing; I didn't do anything to the above code. It should work as the above code does. Would you have time for me to link the page in question?

Comment: When I remove `$('.ItemLink').on('click', function() { ... });` I get an alert that says "_undefined_"

Comment: Hard to debug without code. Post your code to https://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link here please.

Comment: [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/jw52ezbk/1) the jsFiddle but the problem seems to be integration. 

[Here's](http://brilliantcolorsinc.com/Inventory/Inventory.php) the actual page